# Replacing variable in curl request with enviornment variable

Tags: linux, unix, curl

I have to make to curl request

`export URL ='xxxx'`

`export TYPE='ABC'`

`curl -XPOST "$URL/_path/ -d @data.json"`

data.json looks like

`{
   "type": "<to be decided by env variable>",
   ...
   ...
}`

URL enviornment variable gets replaced in curl request.
however i want to replace the value of type in data.json with enviornment variable $TYPE

How can this be done without creating a executable file.

Comment: run `sed` before actual running `curl`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `sed` to replace the placeholder with an actual value.
With the `-d @-` option `curl` can take post data from stdin so you can pipe `sed` right into it. Like this:

`sed -e "s#<to be decided by env variable>#${TYPE}#" data.json | curl "$URL/_path/" -XPOST -d @-`